# Localhost points to different address

Tags: cakephp, server, localhost

I have an app developed with CakePHP and it is working just fine on my local machine. Now, I wanted to develop another app with CakePHP. I installed cake in a different folder, configured vhost and server block and did everything like for the first app. I created an empty app, just basic controller and view and when I type the address for the second app I get the first app!!! Weird thing is that all links are working and when I click I get in browser url like secondapp/companies but the content is firstapp/companies. Once more, the second app is empty, no controllers, views and models, just a basic one. Then I did all that in htdocs, and the same problem occurs (none of the apps wasn't in htdocs, but in folders on E partition).
Can someone please give me some help before I kill myself?
Thank you...

Answer (score -1):

If the problem is not on the database configuration, maybe cache problems ? Try it on a private browser/incognito ?

Comment: What seems to be a problem. In httpd-vhosts.conf I have virtual host blocks for vhosts I created in windows hosts file. When I remove the block for my first app second app is working. When I put a block for my first app then I have the problem.

Comment: Maybe edit your question to include some relevant details of your configuration? Otherwise, we just have to agree that, yeah, it's probably something in your vhosts setup.

Comment: @BryanLoresto firstly welcome to the StackOverflow community. Please do not post an answer unless you believe that it will solve the OPs problem. Use the comments section to ask questions and get more information.

Comment: @DerekFulginiti yes sorry for that, I really would liked to post my answer as a comment but It says I need 50 reputation (currently at 42). I will never do this again once I reach that point. Thank you for your time :)